# Java 2D Array Spiral/Clockwise Traversal

Tags: java, traversal, multidimensional-array, spiral

The problem has been discussed on stackoverflow before, I'm specifically asking for opinion or answers regarding my code and **whether or not it can work with imbalanced 2d arrays without a major overhaul.** The reason it's failing to print the end of some balanced arrays must be some smaller issue. ***Update at the bottom***

Basically we have a 2d array supplied by a command line driven text file. That file has each trial separated by a newline and follows like this: rows;columns;values(white space delimited)

Example: 4;4;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

Output: 1 2 3 4 8 12 16 15 14 13 9 5 6 7 11 10

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package spiralprinting;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author Paul
 */
public class SpiralPrinting {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] lineArray = line.split(";");
            if (lineArray.length > 0) {//ignore blank line inputs
                //Process line of input Here

                //Max ,minimum, and current indexes in our matrix.
                int maxX = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[0]) - 1;
                int maxY = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1]) - 1;
                int minX = 0;
                int minY = 0;
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;

                //Build our matrix
                String[] valueArray = lineArray[2].split("\\s");
                String[][] matrix = new String [Integer.parseInt(lineArray[0])][Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1])];
                int count = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j <= maxY; j++){
                    for (int i = 0; i <= maxX; i++){
                        matrix[i][j] = (valueArray[count]);
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                StringBuilder printString = new StringBuilder();
                //Traverse and print our matrix in a spiral!
                while (maxX > minX && maxY > minY){
                    //Leaving this in and commented so you can see my train of thought.

                    if (x != maxX){
                        while (x < maxX){
                            printString.append(matrix[x][y]).append(" ");
                            x++;
                        }maxX--;
                    }
                    if (y != maxY){
                        while (y < maxY){
                            printString.append(matrix[x][y]).append(" ");
                            y++;
                        }maxY--;
                    }
                    if (x != minX){
                        while (x > minX){
                            printString.append(matrix[x][y]).append(" ");
                            x--;
                        }minX++;
                    }
                    if (y != minY){
                        while (y > minY){
                            printString.append(matrix[x][y]).append(" ");
                            y--;
                        }minY++;
                    }
                    //One border done (4 passes). Next iteration of while-loop begins.
                    x = minX;
                    y = minY;
                }//end of our traversal loop
                //Print it !
                System.out.println(printString.toString().trim());
            }
        }//end of input line analysis
    }
}//end of class
```

Sample input and current output:

4;4;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ---> 1 2 3 4 8 12 16 15 14 13 9 5 6 7 11 10 *good*

3;3;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                      ---> 1 2 3 6 9 8 7 4 *This fails to print the 5*

3;4;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12             ---> 1 2 3 6 9 12 11 10 7 4 *..fails to print the 5, 8 at the end...*

4;3;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12             ---> 1 2 3 4 8 12 11 10 9 5 *..fails to print the last 2 again: 6, 7"*

2;10;1......20                             ---> 1, 2, 4, 6, 8....*good*

After some quick revisions, my issue appears to be that it is not printing the last 2 for some sets. I'm convinced this is a special case and I'm going to sleep on it :)

Any help is still appreciated, especially if you think the issue is larger than I currently believe. My sleepy brain thinks I need 2 special cases to go along with my 4 checks in the while-loop...

Thank you =]

Answer (score 3):

When your debugging something and you just CANT wrap your mind around whats going wrong... break it down into something easy to debug, throw out your hard test cases and try something very simple then move up to harder ones and find where it breaks, heres how i found it.

I commented out all your code where you input the file and made your input to a fixed string:

```
String[] lineArray = ("3;2;" +
                           "1 2 3 " +
                           "6 5 4 ").split(";"); 
// see how the output should be 123456...very easy to see and debug
```

Putting a breakpoint at `while (maxX > minX || maxY > minY)`, I looked at the matrix array and saw that the matrix was of size 2x3 not 3x2, and my numbers were not stored how I would think they should be. And voila problem found.

```
/*if (maxY >= maxX){*/
    // This for loop is what you want
    for (int j = 0; j <= maxY; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxX; i++){
            matrix[i][j] = (valueArray[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }
/*}/*delete this junk/ else if (maxX > maxY){
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxX; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= maxY; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = (valueArray[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}*/
```

This is a fun one for recursion. I assume you already submitted your code for your project so I took a stab at it. Heres what I ended up with: (I left in the printlns so you could see the program flow)

```
// called by System.out.println(getSpiral(matrix,0,0,0,0));

public static String getSpiral(String[][] array, int x, int y, double direction, int turnCount) {

    int [] velocity = getDirection(direction);
    if(x+velocity[0] >= array.length || y+velocity[1] >= array[x].length ||
            x+velocity[0] < 0 || y+velocity[1] < 0 ||
            array[x+velocity[0]][y+velocity[1]].equals("done")) {
        System.out.println("turn");
        if(turnCount>=3)
            return array[x][y];
        return getSpiral(array, x, y, direction+Math.PI/2,turnCount+1);
    }
    String value = array[x][y].toLowerCase();
    array[x][y]="done";
    System.out.println(value);
    return value + " " + getSpiral(array, x+velocity[0], y+velocity[1], direction,0);
}

public static int[] getDirection(double angle) {
    return new int[] {(int)Math.round(Math.cos(angle)), (int)Math.round(Math.sin(angle))};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. It appears as though I was over thinking the initialization. I've edited my post to reflect the current issue. I'll of course spend some more time debugging when I can and update if I figure it out, but I'm still hoping someone might see what must be a big issue. It still fails to print the last number '5' on the 3 by 4 array, and when I submit to the codeeval auto grader, it gets a 10% :-(.

Comment: @spacecadet If you had a 3x3 square and did the entire border. Your minX would start at 0, maxX at 2. Fast forward 1 border loop around, your miX=1,maxX=1,x=1... would your while loop run again? no it would not, this is only the case for squares and only when it reaches the very center because it has narrowed it down to a 1x1 square. Fix? hack that code together and put that center number at the end if its a square matrix :) good luck, god speed.

Comment: That definitely helped a bit! There was an issue there, stemming from when max equaled min. Basically it triggered when the array was balanced, but seemingly had an odd number of elements. My fix was to keep a counter of the elements appended, and if it were less than the total at the end, append on the median X+1 median Y+1. This solved my test cases perfectly..though it has only done slightly better in the auto grader, going from a 10% to a 30%. Sigh @_@

Answer (score 0):

clockwise traversal

```
public static String matrixTraverse(int[][] matrix, int startX, int startY){
    String result = "";
    boolean baseCase = startX + 1 == Math.ceil(matrix[0].length / 2.0)
            || startY + 1 == Math.ceil(matrix.length / 2.0);

    for (int i = startX ; i < matrix[0].length - startX ; i++) {
        result += " " + matrix[startY][i];
    }

    for (int i = startY + 1 ; i < matrix.length - startY - 1 ; i++){
        result += " " + matrix[i][matrix[0].length - 1 - startX];
    }

    for (int i = startX ; (matrix.length - 1 != 2 * startY) && (i < matrix[0].length - startX) ; i++){
        result += " " + matrix[matrix.length - 1 - startY][matrix[0].length - 1 - i];
    }

    for (int i = startY  ; (matrix[0].length - 1 != 2 * startX) && (i < matrix.length - startY - 2) ; i++){
        result += " " + matrix[matrix.length - 2 - i][startX];
    }

    if (!baseCase) {
        result += matrixTraverse(matrix, ++startX, ++startY);
    }

    return result;

}
```